# Set Attribute of Static Model CModel

Tags: php, static, yii, yii-cmodel

I am modifying existing functional code that relied on CActiveRecord.  I am now connecting to sybase, which has no schema driver, so I am rewriting with CModel instead of CActiveRecord.  My problem may be that I don't understand this general OOP concept?

Original: MyModelController.php

```
MyModel::model()->scenario='case1';
```

referring to `::model()` no longer works...because I believe this method only works when the base class is CActiveRecord.

```
/**
 * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
 * @param string $className active record class name.
 * @return ClientProg the static model class
 */
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}
```

How can I set the scenario attribute for MyModel now that it is based off of CModel, in the same fashion as I did when the base class was CActiveRecord?

Comment: Im lost on the static model, what do you use a static model for?

Comment: *Static Method and Properties* Example:$something=MyModel::staticMethod($args).  Don't have instantiate an object, you can use the method anywhere.  I think what I am missing is __get, __set for the static attributes?

Answer (score 0):

When you call model(), it is internaly creating an instance for you the first time, and then refering to this cached object.

if your method its static then do not rely on properties on the instantiated version, you'll get headaches later on.

Check if a static property serve your needs, or pass the scenario as a parameter to your static calls.

anyway, [static its evil](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html), so avoid it if you can.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct.  When extending CActiveRecord, MyModel::model() is calling the static method from the parent class, which reuses the extended static class from which the method was called, if it already exists (the code is shown [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#L381)).  I think it would be useful to implement this same static method when extending CModel, for reasons beyond just the attribute scenario.

Comment: That logic applies specifically to AR, you mentioned sybase, maybe you can take a similar approach to what mongodb suite does https://github.com/canni/YiiMongoDbSuite/blob/master/EMongoDocument.php#L1287